# What leveling precautions should one take with plywood subfloor for engineered hardwood nail down installation?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, plywood, level, engineered-flooring

I installed the nail down engineered hardwood downstairs and did an OK job as far as leveling the subfloor is concerned. I sanded a few high spots down and even used a planer on an especially stubborn spot.

I'm now moving on to the upstairs and I am weary of the same situation. Is there anything else I can do to ensure the subfloor is level?

What are leveling compounds? Are they worth it -or- more of a mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of the sub-floor and what type of material it consists of, leveling is fairly straight forward. If you are leveling a  plywood sub-floor the most critical factor to focus on is the joints and edges of each adjoining piece; they must be level to each other. With a long (48") level and straight edge check each seam screwing down any wayward areas or high spots into the floor joists below. Screw down any sections that when tread on produce a "squeak" or bounce. Use a leveling compound for leveling low spots.